# Uploading to server and creating folder

Tags: server, upload

Hi all so I'm trying to upload some files to my friends computer vis ssh server. But im kind of faltering in the right command to use. Also i want to create a folder within the server so it can stay organized but im a little confused on how to do that as well. Any and all help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AskUbuntu**. In order to connect via SSH, the destination should be reachable. Can you add more in-detail about the network as how these computers are connected, is it internally through a router/switch, or over the internet... etc. This will help us to assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many possibilities to do this, but I prefer these:

- GUI

  Use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/). The only thing you've to to is add `sftp://` before your friend's hostname (or IP address) in the `Host` field.

  FileZilla has support for password and SSH Keys authentication. If you want to use SSH Keys, you'll have to SSH into your friend's computer first (so FileZilla can use your `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`) or add a private key. [More info](https://techtuts.info/2014/04/filezilla-ssh-keys-sftp/).
- CLI

  Use `scp`. The syntax is very easy:

  ```
  scp file1 file2 file3 user@host.name:/path/to/remote/directory
  ```

  `scp` has support for password and SSH Keys authentication.

To use SSH Keys you've to generate them using the following command (on your own PC):

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

If the `.ssh` directory doesn't exist you'll have to create it:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Then **add** the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (**not `id_rsa`**) to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on your friend's computer.

If your friend doesn't have the file you'll have to create it:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nautilus: Click on 'File'>'Connect to Server...' in the toolbar. Then enter ssh://ip_address_of_the_server (e.g. 'ssh://170.132.24.13'). Then you will be asked for your username and your password. After entering those you can browse files and folders or copy, paste and move files between your computer and the server via nautilus.